# Associate class/id to DropDown options in Ember.Select

Tags: ember.js

I have a Ember.Select View, using which I can bind an Array of contents to DropDown list, then using optionValuePath & optionLabelPath I can assign value & labels respectively. But is there something like "optionClassPath" so that I can assign class to the options just like I assigned values

Here's my code snippet:

```js
MyApp = Ember.Application.create();
MyApp.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
  myArr: [{category:"spend",id:"1",cls:"dropdownOption"},{category:"cashflow",id:"2",cls:"dropdownOption"}]
  myVal: ''
});
```

Then in my Handlebars template I used it as

```html
{{view Ember.Select
   contentBinding="MyApp.MyView.myArr"
   selectionBinding="MyApp.MyView.myVal"
   optionLabelPath="content.category"
   optionValuePath="content.id"
   optionClassPath="content.cls"
}}
```

Everything works fine but Ember don't seem to assign specified class to the options.

Comment: Why do you want seperate classes to each option? Just curious :)

Comment: Actually I changed the background of Ember.Select using css to black & foreground to white....But when I click the dropdown, the list has the default background while my text color is still white...So, i thot it would give class to the options & add corresponding css over there.....Can do this using HTML, want to do this is Ember !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this in Ember.js directly, you'll have to `reopen` `Ember.SelectOption` as **@sabithpocker** suggested. So you want something like this, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/bhSVn/:

**Handlebars**:

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" >
    {{view Ember.Select
       contentBinding="MyApp.myController"
       selectionBinding="MyApp.myController.myVal"
       optionLabelPath="content.category"
       optionValuePath="content.id"
       optionClassPath="content.cls"
    }}
</script>​
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
MyApp = Ember.Application.create({});

Ember.SelectOption.reopen({
    classNameBindings: 'optionClass'.w(),
    optionClass: function(){
        var classPath = this.getPath('parentView.optionClassPath');
        return this.getPath(classPath);
    }.property('parentView.optionClassPath')
});

MyApp.myController = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({
  content: [{category:"spend",id:"1",cls:"dropdownOption"},{category:"cashflow",id:"2",cls:"dropdownOption"}],
  myVal: ''
});​
```

**CSS**:

```css
.dropdownOption {
    background-color: green;
}​
```

Comment: Thanks fr this wonderful example, i have one doubt though as I'm kinda new to Ember, what does 'optionClass'.w() mean ?....I guess optionClass refers to the function, but what about w() ?

Comment: Ah, sorry: this is just a convenient method, which is added to the String prototype. It returns the string split by blanks. So `myStringArray: 'a b c'.w()` becomes `myStringArray: ['a', 'b', 'c']`. That's all it does. You might want to take a look at http://code418.com/blog/2012/03/08/useful-emberjs-functions and search for `w()` ...

Comment: That's pretty cool, I wish Ember could document all these stuff instead of just "Getting Started"...Anyways Thanks a lot fr the replies:)

Comment: The official documentation for this is at http://docs.emberjs.com/symbols/Ember.String.html#.w

Answer (score 1):

You can check the source here, this is master not stable release,

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/controls/select.js

for stable release its here https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/0-9-stable/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/controls/select.js

In this also it is clear that there is no option to set any specific classes to each option, check the view responsible for rendering options,

```
Ember.SelectOption = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'option',
  attributeBindings: ['value', 'selected'],

  defaultTemplate: function(context, options) {
    options = { data: options.data, hash: {} };
    Ember.Handlebars.helpers.bind.call(context, "view.label", options);
  },......
```

There are neither attribute binding for class nor class name bindings for option.

If you deliberately want to do this extending just Select might not help,

You will have to extend the Option view to include class as well, then extend Select and use this instead of the base Option view used in handlebars template,

```
Ember.Handlebars.compile('{{#if view.prompt}}<option value>{{view.prompt}}</option>{{/if}}{{#each view.content}}{{view Ember.SelectOption contentBinding="this"}}{{/each}}')
```

You can also think of reopening these classes to make your changes if you want.

**UPDATE**

If you just want to give a specific css to the option you just can use normal css, nothing like this should be needed, this should be required only when you need seperate class for each option.

```
select{
background-color:#000000;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}  

select option{
background-color:red;
    color:yellow;
}
```

A css like this should help you I guess http://jsfiddle.net/Qpkz5/520/

Also if you want seperate css for each option something like this can be used against modern browsers:

```
select option[value="option1"]{
background-color:green;
}
```

Ususally there wont be conditions where we need to add specific class to each "option" that should be the case why Ember Option view doesnt have that extra weight. And for such edge cases its better to create your own extended solution.

Comment: u mean to edit the Ember.Select class by using .reopenClass ? [select.js](http://docs.emberjs.com/symbols/Ember.Select.html#doc=packages_ember-handlebars_lib_controls_select.js&src=true)

Comment: @sabithpoker: Thanks alot :)  this is alot simpler than I thought...Also, reopen comes in handy when the items in the list are Dynamic & each option may have different CSS, in my case I don't need reopen class I guess. I wud like to give +1 for the answer but don't have enough reputation to do so...